# Attempting to do verlet integration

Tags: python, numerical-methods, verlet-integration

I have tried adapting euler method code, and am using euler to calculate the first value so there are two for me to use in verlet but when i plot the graph i just get two perpendicular straight lines.

this is the code:

```py
for t in t_array:

    if t == 0:
        x0 = x
        x1 = x0
        a = -k * x1 / m
        x2 = x1 + dt * v
        v = v + dt * a
        x_list.append(x2)
        v_list.append(v)
    else:
        x2 = x1
        x1 = x0
        x2 = 2*x1 - x0 + dt**2*a
        v = (1/dt)*(x2 - x1)
        x_list.append(x2)
        v_list.append(v)
```

and then i plot a graph using matplotlib.

Comment: Can you post some code that will run?  In particular, you never initialize your x and v lists, and it would be helpful to see what you're doing to plot it.

Comment: If one follows the assignments one finds that the computed values are never used, everything is filled with x0. What was probably intended was `x0,x1 = x1,x2`.

Answer (score -2):

I have implemented a simple Verlet algorithm implementation. You can find the examples [on my own GitHub repository](https://github.com/Smoren/particle-modeling-ipynb).

Here is implementation for Lennard Jones potential:

```py
import numpy as np

def lennard_jones_potential(r, sigma: float, eps: float) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Lennard-Jones potential
    """
    return 4 * eps * np.power(sigma, 12) / np.power(r, 12) - 4 * eps * np.power(sigma, 6) / np.power(r, 6)


def lennard_jones_force(r, sigma: float, eps: float) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Lennard-Jones force (Derivative of LJ potential)
    """
    return 24 * eps * np.power(sigma, 6) / np.power(r, 7) - 48 * eps * np.power(sigma, 12) / np.power(r, 13)


def get_kinetic_energy(m, v):
    """
    Get kinetic energy of particle
    """
    return m * (v ** 2) / 2


def get_verlet_next_x(x, v, f, m, dt):
    """
    Get next position of particle
    """
    a = f / m
    return x + v * dt + a * (dt ** 2) / 2


def get_verlet_next_f(r, rx, sigma: float, eps: float):
    """
    Get next LJ interaction force of particle
    """
    return np.sum(lennard_jones_force(r, sigma, eps) * rx / r)


def get_verlet_next_u(rs, sigma: float, eps: float):
    """
    Get next LJ interaction potential of particle
    """
    return np.sum(lennard_jones_potential(rs, sigma, eps)) / 2


def get_verlet_next_v(v, f, f_next, m, dt):
    """
    Get next velocity of particle using Verlet algorithm
    """
    a, a_next = f / m, f_next / m
    return v + ((a + a_next) * dt) / 2


def get_verlet_next(p: np.ndarray, rx: np.ndarray, ry: np.ndarray, dt: float, sigma: float, eps: float):
    """
    Get next state values of particle using Verlet algorithm
    (force, velocity, potential, kinetic energy)
    """
    r = np.sqrt(np.power(rx, 2) + np.power(ry, 2))

    fx_next = get_verlet_next_f(r, rx, sigma, eps)
    fy_next = get_verlet_next_f(r, ry, sigma, eps)

    vx_next = get_verlet_next_v(p[P_VX], p[P_FX], fx_next, p[P_M], dt)
    vy_next = get_verlet_next_v(p[P_VY], p[P_FY], fy_next, p[P_M], dt)
    v_next = np.sqrt(np.power(vx_next, 2) + np.power(vy_next, 2))

    u_next = get_verlet_next_u(r, sigma, eps)
    ek_next = get_kinetic_energy(p[P_M], v_next)

    return fx_next, fy_next, vx_next, vy_next, v_next, u_next, ek_next

# Indexes of particle properties
P_ID, P_M, P_X, P_Y, P_VX, P_VY, P_FX, P_FY = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
P_X_NEXT, P_Y_NEXT, P_VX_NEXT, P_VY_NEXT, P_FX_NEXT, P_FY_NEXT = 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13

# Indexes of result properties
R_ID, R_M, R_X, R_Y, R_VX, R_VY, R_FX, R_FY, R_U, R_EK, R_ET, R_T = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11

def verlet_algo(particles: np.ndarray, simulation_time: float, dt: float, sigma: float, eps: float) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Verlet algorithm for N particles in 2D space
    """
    time = np.arange(0, simulation_time + dt, dt)

    result = np.zeros(shape=(particles.shape[0], time.shape[0], 12))

    for i in range(particles.shape[0]):
        result[i, :, R_ID] = np.repeat(particles[i, P_ID], result.shape[1])
        result[i, :, R_M] = np.repeat(particles[i, P_M], result.shape[1])

    result[:, 0, R_X] = particles[:, P_X]
    result[:, 0, R_Y] = particles[:, P_Y]
    result[:, 0, R_VX] = particles[:, P_VX]
    result[:, 0, R_VY] = particles[:, P_VY]
    result[:, 0, R_FX] = particles[:, P_FX]
    result[:, 0, R_FY] = particles[:, P_FY]
    result[:, 0, R_U] = 0
    result[:, 0, R_EK] = 0
    result[:, 0, R_ET] = 0
    result[:, :, R_T] = time

    # Calculate the initial forces and energies
    for i in range(particles.shape[0]):
        p = particles[i]
        p_id = p[P_ID].astype(np.int64)
        neighbours = particles[particles[:, P_ID] != p[P_ID]]

        rx = neighbours[:, P_X] - p[P_X]
        ry = neighbours[:, P_Y] - p[P_Y]

        fx, fy, vx, vy, v, u, ek = get_verlet_next(p, rx, ry, dt, sigma, eps)

        particles[i, P_FX] = fx
        particles[i, P_FY] = fy

        result[p_id, 0, R_FX] = fx
        result[p_id, 0, R_FY] = fy
        result[p_id, 0, R_U] = u
        result[p_id, 0, R_EK] = ek
        result[p_id, 0, R_ET] = ek + u

    for curr in range(len(time) - 1):
        next = curr + 1

        # Get following coordinates of all particles:
        particles[:, P_X_NEXT] = get_verlet_next_x(particles[:, P_X], particles[:, P_VX], particles[:, P_FX],
                                                   particles[:, P_M], dt)
        particles[:, P_Y_NEXT] = get_verlet_next_x(particles[:, P_Y], particles[:, P_VY], particles[:, P_FY],
                                                   particles[:, P_M], dt)

        for i in range(particles.shape[0]):
            p = particles[i]
            p_id = p[P_ID].astype(np.int64)
            neighbours = particles[particles[:, P_ID] != p[P_ID]]

            # Get distances between current particle and all other particles:
            rx = neighbours[:, P_X_NEXT] - p[P_X_NEXT]
            ry = neighbours[:, P_Y_NEXT] - p[P_Y_NEXT]

            # Get next force, velocity and energies for current particle using verlet algorithm:
            fx_next, fy_next, vx_next, vy_next, v_next, u_next, ek_next = get_verlet_next(p, rx, ry, dt, sigma, eps)

            # Save next values of current particle:
            p[P_VX_NEXT] = vx_next
            p[P_VY_NEXT] = vy_next
            p[P_FX_NEXT] = fx_next
            p[P_FY_NEXT] = fy_next

            # Save next values of current particle to result array:
            result[p_id, next, R_X] = p[P_X_NEXT]
            result[p_id, next, R_Y] = p[P_Y_NEXT]
            result[p_id, next, R_VX] = vx_next
            result[p_id, next, R_VY] = vy_next
            result[p_id, next, R_FX] = fx_next
            result[p_id, next, R_FY] = fy_next
            result[p_id, next, R_U] = u_next
            result[p_id, next, R_EK] = ek_next
            result[p_id, next, R_ET] = ek_next + u_next

        # Apply next values to all particles:
        particles[:, P_X] = particles[:, P_X_NEXT]
        particles[:, P_Y] = particles[:, P_Y_NEXT]
        particles[:, P_VX] = particles[:, P_VX_NEXT]
        particles[:, P_VY] = particles[:, P_VY_NEXT]
        particles[:, P_FX] = particles[:, P_FX_NEXT]
        particles[:, P_FY] = particles[:, P_FY_NEXT]

    return result

particles = np.array([
    #id,m, x,  y,  vx,vy,fx,fy,ẋ, ẏ, vẋ,vẏ,fẋ,fẏ (ẋ == x_next, ...)
    [0, 2, 11, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 10, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 3, 12, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
], dtype=np.float64)

result = verlet_algo(particles, simulation_time=50, dt=0.002, sigma=1, eps=0.7, animate=True)
```

Energies plot:

[image]

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers) Also note that having a similar username to URL doesn't make attribution, putting this at risk of being deleted for being spam. See [how not to be a spammer](/help.promotion).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I've added code example with comments to my answer.